# How can I send spoofed packets in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, spoofing

In order to test a firewall, I want to send malformed packets to its interface, regardless of my routing table.

Is there a way to ask linux "send this exact tcp package, to this MAC address, regardless of any network configuration on the system"? I assume I'll need root acccess, but that's OK.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `nmap` in root, it can already send quite all advanced spoofed packets with just some flags.

Answer (score 4):

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is commonly used tool for this purpose. It can be used for creating any kind of packets.

Answer (score 2):

[hping3](http://wiki.hping.org/) gets cited as a way to do this sort of thing, without having to learn Python.

Answer (score 2):

All previous answers are good, there is a number of very good tools to do that. If you want to take it a step further, writing a simple injector in C is actually quite easy.

Here is a sample of code I wrote a few years back: http://jve.linuxwall.info/ressources/code/forgetcp.c

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Small thing, though, for the `-c` command line option, did you really mean `p.tcp.check = (int)optarg;` or were you thinking of using `p.tcp.check = atoi(optarg);`?